# How to show that $ \ln( \frac{x+1}{x}) * (x+1) - 1$ is non negative and monotonically decreasing

Tags: calculus, logarithms

we are given an excercise where we have to show that:

$$ \ln( \frac{x+1}{x}) \cdot (x+1) - 1$$

is non-negativ and monotonically decreasing with $x\geq 0$. I took the derivative which yields:

$$ \frac{x \cdot \ln(\frac{x+1}{x})-1}{x}$$

which didn't tell me a lot.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you familiar with $\ln (1+t)<t$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let $$f(x) = (x + 1) \ln\left(\frac{x + 1}{x}\right) - 1 = (x + 1) \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) - 1$$

Now let us construct some useful identities. Let $t \geq 0$. From the definition of the exponential function:

$$e^t = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^i}{i!} \implies e^t - 1 - t = \sum_{i = 2}^{\infty} \frac{t^i}{i!} \geq 0 \implies e^t \geq 1 + t \implies t \geq \ln(1 + t) \, \, \, \, (1)$$

Also note:

$$t \geq \ln(t + 1) \implies \frac{1}{t} - 1 \geq \ln(t^{-1}) \implies 1 - \frac{1}{t} \leq \ln(t) \, \, \, \, \forall \, \, \, \, t \geq 0 \, \, \, \, (2)$$

We can now construct a lower bound for $f(x)$ based $(2)$:

$$\ln(1 + \frac{1}{x}) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{1 +  \frac{1}{x}} =  \frac{1}{x + 1}$$
$$(x + 1)\ln(1 + \frac{1}{x}) \geq  1$$
$$f(x) \geq  0$$

Taking a derivative of $f(x)$ gives us

$$f'(x) = \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) - \frac{1}{x} < 0$$

where the inequality is established by invoking $(1)$.

Therefore $f(x)$ is non-negative and monotonically decreasing for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: $e^t = 1 + t + O(t^2)$ does not imply $e^t \geq 1 + t$. It is true, but this is not valid. Use $\ln(1+x) = \int_0^x dt/(1+t)$ to show $\ln(1+x) < x$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Hi Marty. I’m a little confused, $e^x$ is defined as a sum of the powers of $x$ with positive coefficients. If $x \geq 0$ then every term in that sum is a positive number. Therefore removing all terms that involve powers higher than linear order would surely make the resulting sum less than the original sum unless $x=0$, for which the new sum is equal to the original sum. 

Therefore $e^x \geq 1 + x$ for $x \geq 0$.

If you could elaborate on why my reasoning is flawed, I’d be glad to update my answer.

Thanks

Comment: You need the big-oh term to be non-negative to conclude $\ge$. A big-oh term can be negative.

Comment: In this case, if $x \geq 0$ then the big-oh term is positive. I will drop the big-oh notation to make this more obvious. Thanks for your help!